# Plotting the solution of a cubic equation against a coefficient in the equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have to plot the *solution* of the following equation against the coefficient $L$. Since it's a cubic equation, I'd like to filter out the real solution first and plot that then. The equation is $L r^3 - 3 r + 6 M = 0$.

PS: I have been trying various variants over the following piece of code, but to no use:

```
f[L_, M_, r_] := L r^3 - 3 r + 6 M
Plot[r /.NSolve[f[L,10,r] == 0, r,Reals], {L,-1,1}]
```

Could you let me know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `Root[]`? To help in picking out which one to use, you can use `Discriminant[]`.

Comment: Have you tried doing `Solve[f[L, 10, r] == 0, r]` and using those results first? You shouldn't be doing an `NSolve` in a plot if you don't have to.
`sol = r /. Solve[f[L, 10, r] == 0, r,Reals];
Plot[sol, {L, -1, 1}]`

Comment: That helps @Histograms. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can plot them with `ContourPlot[f[L, 10., r] == 0, {L, -1, 2}, {r, -8, 20}]`.  -- And you're only interested in real roots?

Comment: Yes, I'm only interested in real plots.

Comment: In particular, you might want to look at the results of `Reduce[Discriminant[f[L, M, r], r] < 0, {M, L}]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., That does in fact give me more insight into my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It works fine in Mathematica 10. Even as 3D Plot as function of parameters L and M:

```
Plot3D[r /. NSolve[f[L, M, r] == 0, r, Reals], {L, -1, 1}, {M, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be that will do:

```
    Clear[ss, n];
eq = L r^3 - 3 r + 6 M == 0;
ss[L_, M_] = Solve[eq, r];

Manipulate[
 Plot[{ss[L, M][[1, 1, 2]], ss[L, M][[2, 1, 2]], 
   ss[L, M][[3, 1, 2]]}, {L, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}], {{M, 0.6}, 0, 1}]
```

giving

[image]

Have fun!